# how to make a deployable launch shortcut for GE viewers that can be used on iOS

Tags: geocortex, geocortex-essentials

How can I make launch shortcuts for GE viewers that can be used on mobile devices, specifically on iOS? I want to launch GE through the mobile device management software, so the users can feel like they are opening an app and we can manage who has access better.

I searched around but could not find any examples online or help articles directly related to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this javascript widget called AddToHome (https://github.com/cubiq/add-to-homescreen) which I should be able to launch from a workflow at startup. This will allow the users to get a "custom disclaimer".